# Difference between `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/pg_hba.conf` and `/var/lib/pgsql/pg_hba.conf`

Tags: postgresql, centos-6

From http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html, it says:

> A default pg_hba.conf file is installed when the data directory is initialized by initdb.

I would assume when I run `initdb`, it will generate a file at `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/pg_hba.conf`. However, it also generates a file at `/var/lib/pgsql/pg_hba.conf`.

1. Could anyone explain how do I end up with two pg_hba.conf with different content?
2. Which one eventually will be used?

Comment: Could you post the output of `ls -l /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/pg_hba.conf /var/lib/pgsql/pg_hba.conf`? Is one a link to the other? Also check if they are different: `diff /var/lib/pgsql/pg_hba.conf /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/pg_hba.conf`

Comment: Thanks @terdon! Following your lead, I figured out the problem.  The problem was I did not correctly override the pg_hba.conf, which results in two pg_hba.conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the problem:

I was using **Vagrant** to create the **Virtual Machine**, and using **Puppet** to install **postgresql-9.1**. The puppet has a postgresql-service module, which includes two parts that are relevant to this question:

1. initdb, which essentially runs:

   ```
   /sbin/service postgresql-9.1 initdb
   ```

   The result of this command is to create the directory:

   ```
   /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data
   ```

   Inside this directory, there is a default pg_hba.conf
2. Override the default `pg_hba.conf` with our `customized pg_hba.conf`

   The problem I had was I output `customized pg_hba.conf` to `/var/lib/pgsql` instead of `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data`.

Hope the answer will help other people to avoid similar problems.